# PHP Fatal error: Class 'SassParser' not found

Tags: php, drupal-7, sass

I just installed the [peroxide](https://github.com/codeincarnate/peroxide) HAML/SASS engine for Drupal 7.x and its [oxygen](https://github.com/codeincarnate/oxygen) theme, activated and *Set as default*, then gave `chmod -R 777 sites/all` just to be sure I don't get any rwx errors.
I have the *sass* (ruby gem version) installed(in `sass: /usr/local/bin/sass /home/danthe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/sass`)

I see a blank page now, can't even login to admin panel, everything is blank(`cause of the PHP Fatal Error).

My [log](http://pastie.org/10301160) says

```
[Sun Jul 19 21:14:19.607260 2015] [:error] [pid 2507] [client 127.0.0.1:42531] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'SassParser' not found in /home/danthe/public_html/AtmTopTech/sites/all/themes/engines/peroxide/peroxide.engine on line 186
sh: 1: sass: not found
[Sun Jul 19 21:14:19.656532 2015] [:error] [pid 1424] [client 127.0.0.1:42532] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'SassParser' not found in /home/danthe/public_html/AtmTopTech/sites/all/themes/engines/peroxide/peroxide.engine on line 186
[Sun Jul 19 21:14:19.740176 2015] [:error] [pid 2506] [client 127.0.0.1:42533] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'SassParser' not found in /home/danthe/public_html/AtmTopTech/sites/all/themes/engines/peroxide/peroxide.engine on line 186
[Sun Jul 19 21:14:19.815207 2015] [:error] [pid 1427] [client 127.0.0.1:42534] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'SassParser' not found in /home/danthe/public_html/AtmTopTech/sites/all/themes/engines/peroxide/peroxide.engine on line 186
```

This is in my ../peroxine.engine on line 186

```
  // Setup the Sass Parser
  $options = _peroxide_get_sass_options($theme);
  $parser = new SassParser($options);
```

Comment: error seems clear, not sure how else to help

Answer (score 1):

[peroxide](https://github.com/codeincarnate/peroxide) does not rely on entirely Ruby version of SASS compiler, it's only capable of compiling with Ruby version of compiler. You have to clone the repository with the engine recursively, as it is specified in [Installation guide](https://github.com/codeincarnate/peroxide#installation).

Peroxide uses [phamlp](https://github.com/codeincarnate/phamlp) as SASS compiler, it is specified as Git Sub-module for the Peroxide repository.

```
cd sites/all/themes (or whatever your theme directory is)
mkdir engines
cd engines
git clone --recursive git://github.com/codeincarnate/peroxide.git
```

The error that you're having is not caused by permissions, it's a Fatal Error in php in [peroxide.engine#L186](https://github.com/codeincarnate/peroxide/blob/master/peroxide.engine#L186)

The PHP script fails to create a new instance of `SassParser` object, which is defined in [/phamlp/blob/master/sass/SassParser.php](https://github.com/codeincarnate/phamlp/blob/master/sass/SassParser.php)

Please make sure that the folder is present and contains the phamlp source code. `/home/danthe/public_html/AtmTopTech/sites/all/themes/engines/peroxide/phamlp`

Comment: I followed the steps one by one, cloned it recursively in ``sites/all/themes``, also it says there that you have to give file permissions to it in order to function properly.

If you see before line 186, it [checks](https://github.com/codeincarnate/peroxide/blob/master/peroxide.engine#L164-L168) whether I have a ruby version of Sass installed
  // Test for Ruby version first
  @exec("sass -v", $op, $ret);
  if($ret != 0) {
    include_once $path . 'phamlp/sass/SassParser.php';
  }

Comment: @MincăDanielAndrei yeah, it is capable of compiling SASS using the Ruby compiler, but in order to build the cache for theme `.sass` files, it uses only `phamlp`, it's a dependency.